# Code works with a static PHP value but not a dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to create a website where I create dropdown menus filled by an SQL query and based on choices I make, different kinds of dropdown menus will appear.

I'm currently on my second dropdown menu which works, if I hardcode a certain value in there, but doesn't work if I try to use a dynamic value based on the user's selection.

Since I need to figure out what the user is selecting, and based on that, make a new dynamic selection, I tried getting the user-based info with javascript. Since I'm still very new to this, I tried saving that info to a cookie and then reading it with PHP to create a new list, but that didn't work the way I intended. It didn't update the page without a refresh, so I searched on and found AJAX.

With it, I was able to get the user selected dropdown info and send it back to PHP, which I need to do, because I need to run a new SQL query based on user's selection. And here is where I've completely ran out of ideas.

When I use AJAX and look at my browser's console, the supposed new dropdown menu is there in the console, but it just shows up as a blank dropdown menu on the webpage $varClass = $_POST['valitudKlass']; but if I set $varClass manually, then the script works great and generates me the list.

This is my function than runs whenever the user selects something in the first dropdown menu. It's supposed to get the value of the currently selected dropdown item and send it to pass.php

```
function valiKlass() {
    var valitudKlass = $("#klass option:selected").text();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'pass.php',
        data: {valitudKlass : valitudKlass},
        success:(function(data){
             console.log(data);
        })
    });
    $("#valiNimi").load("pass.php");
}
```

This is pass.php that's supposed to receive the information about what the user selected, then based on that, send a new SQL query and generate a new dropdown list:

```
<?php
    require_once "config.php";
    echo "Vali nimi;";
    echo "<select name='nimi' id='nimi'>";
    $varClass = $_POST['valitudKlass'];
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT firstname FROM `students` WHERE class = '$varClass'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<option value ='" . $row['firstname'] . "'>" . $row['firstname'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

I have only coded in C# in the past, so I'm completely new to both PHP and javascript, which I picked up a few days ago in order to help out some people I know, but this problem is slowly overwhelming me. I'd like to overcome it, so I appreciate any help you could give me.

Comment: In `pass.php` build the select up as a single variable and echo it after the select has been completely built. If you look at the browser console you will probably see that all that is coming back from calling `pass.php` is "Vali nimi".

Comment: Also, if you are new to PHP, you most definetly do not want to WASTE your time learning `mysqli`. Take a look at PHP PDO. https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `$.ajax` call sends the value to the server, your `load()` call doesn't.
Just put the result from the `$.ajax` in your page and remove the `load()` call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'pass.php',
    data: {valitudKlass : valitudKlass},
    success:(function(data){
        $("#valiNimi").html(data);
    })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Build the entire select in a variable before echoing it.

```
require_once "config.php";

$sendback = 'Vali nimi;<select name="nimi" id="nimi">';

$varClass = $_POST['valitudKlass'];
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT firstname FROM `students` WHERE class = '$varClass'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $sendback .= "<option value ='" . $row['firstname'] . "'>" . $row['firstname'] . "</option>";
 }
 echo $sendback . '</select>';
```